# Cruise control repair

Tags: dodge

I have a 1983 Dodge ram Conversion van. I once got on the computer and found a video of how to repair the Cruise control but never got to do it and can't find the video. Can anybody tell me where to find the cruise control for a start then how to repair it. Thanks. Norm.

Comment: Searching on "repair cruise control dodge 1983" found some likely looking videos and web pages.